# Reference Cloud Formation property within same instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a Cloud Formation template where I am looking to set an environment variable `TAKE_ACTION` on my API Gateway Stage with one of the endpoints of the stage, which requires the stage name, but when I access it using `{"Ref":"MyApiStage"}` I get a circular reference error.

Is there a workaround for what I'm trying to accomplish?

```
   {
      "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
      "Transform":"AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
      "Description":"my POC.",
      "Resources":{
        "MyApiStage":{
          "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Stage",
          "Properties":{
            "DeploymentId":{ "Ref":"ApiDeployment"},
            "MethodSettings":[
              {
                "DataTraceEnabled":true,
                "HttpMethod":"*",
                "LoggingLevel":"INFO",
                "ResourcePath":"/"
              }
            ],
            "RestApiId":{ "Ref":"MyApi" },
            "StageName":"Prod",
            "Variables":{
              "TAKE_ACTION" : {"Fn::Join" : 
                ["", 
                ["https://", 
                 {"Ref" : "ApiDeployment"}, 
                 ".execute-api.", 
                 {"Ref":"AWS::Region"}, 
                 ".amazonaws.com/", 
                 {"Ref":"MyApiStage"} 
              ] ]  }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: As `"Ref":"MyApiStage"` is just going to return the `StageName` of `Prod` you could just hardcode it.

Comment: You could have a custom domain record set for that endpoint. Or you could drop the `"Transform":"AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",` and use basic CloudFormation resource type so the stage would be a separate resource therefore allowing your to reference it from your API. However, I would reconsider my design choices because it does look like an architectural faux-pas.